# I am trying to deploy my container image into container apps from Azure Container Registry I am getting invalid web hook error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, docker-registry

I am trying to deploy into container apps using ARM templates, but I am getting an error like:

> ##[error]WebhookInvalidParameterValue: The following field(s) are either invalid or missing.
> Invalid value: "naniacr.azurecr.io/builddeploy: latest": could not parse reference: naniacr.azurecr.io/builddeploy: latest

Is there any other way to pull latest tag image from Azure Container Registry?

I want to pull the latest tag image from container registry

Comment: Could you check that the `latest` tag existsfor the image you are trying to pull ?

Comment: Also do you have network restriction for ACR ? That could cause the issue

Answer (score -1):

> ##[error]WebhookInvalidParameterValue: The following field(s) are either invalid or missing.
> Invalid value: "naniacr.azurecr.io/builddeploy: latest": could not parse reference: naniacr.azurecr.io/builddeploy: latest

After seeing the error, it seems there is an issue with image. I see there is a **space in between the image name and the tag which is not valid**.
I have deployed the conatiner app via ARM template using the below code.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "containerappName": {
        "defaultValue": "contappdrinkwaterarm02",
        "type": "String"
      },
      "location": {
        "defaultValue": "eastus",
        "type": "String"
      },
      "environment_name": {
        "defaultValue": "managedEnvironment-vgoonavrg-ae45",
        "type": "String"
      },
      "container_image": {
        "defaultValue": "acrtestwishgood.azurecr.io/nginxc:latest",
        "type": "String"
      },
      "registry_password": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.App/containerApps",
        "name": "[parameters('containerappName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "identity": {
          "type": "None"
        },
        "properties": {
          "managedEnvironmentId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments', parameters('environment_name'))]",
          "configuration": {
            "secrets": [
              {
                "name": "myregistrypassword",
                "value": "[parameters('registry_password')]"
              }
            ],
            "ingress": {
              "external": true,
              "targetPort": 80,
              "allowInsecure": false,
              "traffic": [
                {
                  "latestRevision": true,
                  "weight": 100
                }
              ]
            },
            "registries": [
              {
                "server": "acrtestwishgood.azurecr.io",
                "username": "acrtestwishgood",
                "passwordSecretRef": "myregistrypassword"
              }
            ],
            "dapr": {
              "appId": "[parameters('containerappName')]",
              "appPort": 80,
              "appProtocol": "http",
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          "template": {
            "revisionSuffix": "myrevision",
            "containers": [
              {
                "name": "main",
                "image": "[parameters('container_image')]",
                "env": [
                  {
                    "name": "HTTP_PORT",
                    "value": "80"
                  }
                ],
                "resources": {
                  "cpu": 0.5,
                  "memory": "1Gi"
                }
              }
            ],
            "scale": {
              "minReplicas": 1,
              "maxReplicas": 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In my case I am providing container registry password during template deployment.
Verify the portal once deployment completed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "containers": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "#appname#",
                    "image": "naniacr.azurecr.io/builddeploy:latest",
                    "command": [],
                    "resources": {
                        "cpu": 0.25,
                        "memory": ".5Gi"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

Comment: i tried with the ARM but if i mentioned latest it is showing errors but if i give tag number it works fine  i want to deploy the latest Tag but i don't want to give the tag number manually

Comment: @user21768949 have you verified whether the image with the latest tag exists in ACR?

Comment: i am using the tag number it is working fine but i want to pull the latest image i got generated from the build pipeline and i don't want to give tag number every time i run the release pipeline